# Is oddo v8 custom app compatible with odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10

I need help and i am new to odoo erp. i just installed odoo version 10 and installed APPs working fine. However, following odoo server error occured, when i try to installing OCA custom App as developed for odoo version 8. what steps to take when installing odoo v8 module on odoo 10
Please provide help regarding this issue.

Your help will be highly appreciated

Regards
Afzal

odoo server error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 642, in _handle_exception
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 684, in dispatch
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 334, in _call_function
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 101, in wrapper
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 327, in checked_call
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 942, in **call**
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 507, in response_wrap
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 899, in call_button
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 689, in call_kw
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\module\module.py", line 412, in button_immediate_install
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\module\module.py", line 486, in _button_immediate_function
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 83, in new
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 377, in load_modules
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 270, in load_marked_modules
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 96, in _load_data
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 845, in convert_file
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 915, in convert_xml_import
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 796, in parse
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 799, in parse
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 777, in _tag_template
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 707, in _tag_record
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 1250, in _update
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 365, in create
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3865, in create
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1058, in determine_inverse
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 220, in _inverse_arch
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 383, in write
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3576, in write
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3742, in _write
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1083, in _validate_fields
>   ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Element '' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `web_context_tunnel qunit`
[view_id: 869, xml_id: n/a, model: n/a, parent_id: 173]
None" while parsing None:10, near

Comment: You need to migrate the source code to make it work in Odoo 10

Answer (score 0):

No, most of odoo8 modules do not support odoo10 as there is so much change in coding patterns and orm methods.
On OCA, supported versions are always mentioned.